# How to use different style on normal and large Title at navigationBar?

Tags: swift

I'm using large title in my Navigation Bar. I also styled it to have an shadow like this.

https://i.ibb.co/WckRgVb/file-3.jpg

Now i want to hide the shadow, but only on the large title, when i scroll down (normal size) the shadow should appear.

This ist the code, I'm using at the moment:

```swift
extension UINavigationController {

    // Shado Style for Nav Bar
    func shadowStyle(largeTitle: Bool = false) {
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
        navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.80, green:0.80, blue:0.80, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 5

        if(largeTitle) {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
                navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            }
        } else {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
                navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it in the ViewController like this:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.shadowStyle(largeTitle: true)

    // other code
}
```

My question is, how to remove the shadow, only when the large title is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i found it out myself.

I just need to set the `navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity` based on the height of the Navigation Bar: `navigationBar.frame.size.height`

Answer (score 0):

Check this bool : `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   if self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles {
        self.navigationController?.shadowStyle(largeTitle: true)
   }

   // other code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this on a single bar just set it directly.

whenever you want to, To change all bars, set it inside your `AppDelegate` using the appearance proxy for `UINavigationBar` so that it kicks in before the first bar is loaded.

Here's an example that makes title text be 18-point Georgia Bold in blue:

```
 let attrs = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 18)!
    ]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attrs
```